# ASP.net MVC deployment to IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, deployment, iis-7

I'm trying to deploy a MVC application to a news Server, I have .net framework 4 and ASP.net MVC2 installed. My app pool is assigned to .net 4, integrated mode. But for some reason, the routing is not happening properly. I am getting a 404 error on links and not properly routed to the controller. What am i missing here? Is it might be order of installation of .net framework and IIS?

Comment: Do you have web.config in Views folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Or try to [debug routing](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

Comment: i removed <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
and it seems to be good now

Answer (score 1):

Your app is probably compiled against .Net Framework Version 2.0. Change your app pool to 2.0 and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you got a 404 error that is because the global.asax is not being executed.
Check out if the IIS is configured to "Check if the Directory/File exists", cause the IIS is default configured to check first if the request exists on the server ... MVC doesn't use the 'real' path, *per se*.

Hope it helps ;)

**EDIT**
Try to log something at the time the routing is working ... I mean when the Route inside the global asax is called and check out if the mapping is called...

Comment: I dont think that should be an issue with IIS7, if the file doesnt exists, it MVCRouteHandler should be invoked,

Comment: If the IIS is checking for the file existance before executing the app it's not gonna work, cause it's not gonna call the application.